# Variable becomes empty after entering for-loop

Tags: c++, list, for-loop

```
        MA=ArrayToList(A);
        MB=ArrayToList(B);
        MC=ArrayToList(C);
        MD=ArrayToList(D);
        if(MB==NULL) cout<<"B is EMPTY"; // It's OK here
        for(;MA!=NULL;MA=MA->next){
            if(MB==NULL) cout<<"B is EMPTY"; // MB==NULL, same as MC
            bool f = true;
            for(;f && MB!=NULL;MB=MB->next)
                if(MA->elem==MB->elem) f = false;
            for(;f && MC!=NULL;MC=MC->next)
                if(MA->elem==MC->elem) f = false;
            if(f){
                mE=new mult;
                mE->elem=MA->elem;
                mE->next=ME;
                ME=mE;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that MB and MC become empty right after this string

```
        for(;MA!=NULL;MA=MA->next){
```

Any suggestions?

**UPD:** 
MB and MC become empty before first iteration (before the iteration body), not after it finishes.
This is how MB looks like

```
typedef struct st
{
   char elem;
   struct st* next;
}mult;
```

This is what ArrayToList does:

```
mult* ArrayToList(char *Arr)
{
    mult *head=NULL, *phead;
    for (int i = 0; Arr[i]; i++)
    {
        phead = new mult;
        phead->elem = Arr[i];
        phead->next = head;
        head = phead;
    }
    return head;
}
```

How i see it:

```
typedef struct st
{
   char elem;
   struct st* next;
}mult;

int main(){
//initialization of mult *MA, *MB, *MC, *MD;
//at this point all 4 variables are not empty and can be shown correctly
for(;MA!=NULL;MA=MA->next){
    //right after this point MB and MC somehow become empty, MA is still OK
    //some stuff
}
}
```

Hope it is more clear now

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You should examine more. for example, use this to check if `B is EMPTY` is shown in only second loop or later. `if(MB==NULL) cout<<"B is EMPTY"; else cout<<<"B is not EMPTY";`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `MB` should be `NULL` after the first loop since there are loops that continues until `MB` and `MC` becomes `NULL`.

Comment: What does `ArrayToList` do? Could it happen (by accident) that several pointers point to the same location?

Comment: As @MikeCAT pointed out, `MB` and `MC` are becoming `NULL` after the first loop, what you can do is add `MB=ArrayToList(B); MC=ArrayToList(C);` before the end of the for loop. This should make your program work. Although I am still unclear about what you're trying.

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar `ArrayToList` may do something not good. We don't know about it. Backing up `MB` and `MC` before the inner loops and restoring them after the loops should work.

Comment: `B is EMPTY` appears each iteration.

Comment: No way. I think just compareing won't change their values. Or is `MA` a class and does it have some overloaded `!=` operators?

Comment: MA is a structure and is used in this code part only, so seems there shouldn't be overload